# sql query producing three times as many results as it should

Tags: sql

I'm trying perform an SQL query. However, when I use an inner join in returns three lots of the same entry.

My SQL code is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM {} INNER JOIN plates ON {}.name=plates.carname
WHERE name IN ({})
  AND size BETWEEN {} AND {};'.format(Table, Table, qmarks, size_lower, size_upper
```

this produces the result:

```
500518||blue|2|18| 
500518||blue|2|18| 
500518||blue|2|18| 
500519||red|4|183|
500519||red|4|183|
500519||red|4|183|
```

I want it to produce the result:

```
500518||blue|2|18| 
500519||red|4|183|
```

I know the problem is with the inner join but I'm not sure why. What's wrong with the SQL query?

Comment: Try SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Comment: select col1,col2 ... from table group by col1,col2

Comment: Just to be clear these entries don't appear multiple times in the database just in the query when I use an inner join. Therefore distinct doesn't work, and neither does select specific columns

Comment: We cannot know what happens if you dont tell us what data do you have in first table and what data do you have in second table. As it is, we don't even know what the columns are, because you `SELECT *`